# Scraping next pages Google Scholar profile

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib, google-scholar

I need the information of professors based on areas interest and university and the best source for this I think is google scholar. I tried to scrape google scholar profiles without SERP API, and I used of request package and then get a 429 error, I couldn't solve it then used URllib and it work well. But now I have two problems:

1_ I want to **scrap next pages of profiles** if there is, else break loop, How do I do it?, "in my code doesn't go next page and doesn't break the loop":

2_ I notice a problem that the query just returns a matching case, and doesn't return a substring, for ex. If I write exactly "Tropical_Forest_Ecology" then it returns a particular researcher - say "John Doe". But when I'm looking for ecology at Michigan State University, and as a result, it doesn't return "John Doe". How do I solve it that returns any word even in substring?

[image: profile]

Code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
from time import sleep


def Scrape_profiles(label,university_name,country):
    
    for uni in university_name:
        params = {
            "view_op": "search_authors",           # author results
            "mauthors": f'label:{label} "{uni}"',  # search query
            "hl": "en",                            # language
            "astart": 0,                           # page number
            "engine": "google_scholar_profiles",
        }

        
        paper_repos_dict = {
                    'name' : [],
                    'email' : [],
                    'affiliations' : [],
                    'Citation' : [],
                    'interests' : [],
                    'uni' : [],
                    'country' : []}

    
        while True:
            url = r"https://scholar.google.com/citations?"
            data = urllib.parse.urlencode(params) 
            req = urllib.request.Request(url+data,headers={'cookie': '<my cookie>'}) 
            resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
            
            soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, 'html5lib')
            proftags = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "gsc_1usr" })

            for mytag in proftags:
                paper_repos_dict['name'].append(mytag.find("h3", {"class": "gs_ai_name" }).text),
                paper_repos_dict['email'].append(mytag.find("div", {"class": "gs_ai_eml" }).text),
                paper_repos_dict['affiliations'].append(mytag.find("div", {"class": "gs_ai_aff" }).text),
                paper_repos_dict['Citation'].append(mytag.find("div", {"class": "gs_ai_cby" }).text[8:]),
                paper_repos_dict['interests'].append([item.text for item in mytag.findAll("a", {"class": "gs_ai_one_int"})]), 
                paper_repos_dict['uni'].append(university_name),
                paper_repos_dict['country'].append(country)
                sleep(0.2)
            
            
            # if next page token
            if soup.select_one("button.gs_btnPR")["onclick"]:
                params["after_author"] = re.search(r"after_author\\x3d(.*)\\x26", str(soup.select_one("button.gs_btnPR")["onclick"])).group(1)  # -> XB0HAMS9__8J
                params["astart"] += 10
            else:
                break
                
                

        return paper_repos_dict
    
    
label="Remote_Sensing"
university_name=["Michigan University"]
country = 'USA'


Scrape_profiles(label,university_name,"usa")
```

[Here](https://dev.to/dmitryzub/scrape-google-scholar-with-python-32oh) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331881/prevent-503-error-when-scraping-google-scholar/71046843#71046843) there were good examples.

Comment: For the next page token/link, instead of using regex, you could try wrapping `onclick` as a u string and [evaluate](https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/answers/how-to-differentiate-eval()-and-ast.literal_eval()-in-python) and then either form a full link or [parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) `after_author` ([view example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuLHT.png))

Comment: about the second issue, are you formatting the author into `mauthors` with *`label...`*? Because I think only the tags are added as label, otherwise `mauthors` could just be `f'{author} {uni}'` etc

Comment: @Driftr95 in this case labels have assigned to tags.

Comment: yes, but "John Doe" [etc] is not a tag - what do the parameters look like when you're searching for "John Doe"?

Comment: @Driftr95 you know, i don't search for name.
i search for area of interest (tags) and filter it by university name. the mauthor doesn't return name of authors.
see [here](https://serpapi.com/blog/scrape-google-scholar-profiles-from-a-certain-university-in-python/)

Comment: Sorry, it seems I totally misunderstood the second part of your q. So, the thing is, `label:ecology` will obviously return only those with the ecology tag listed in their interests,  `"ecology"` would look for those with the exact word "ecology" in their affiliations field, and just `ecology` (no quotes) SHOULD look for ecology *and related words*, but while you and I both know that forestry *is* very much related to ecology, it's not listed as a synonym for ecology in most sites [the way "environment" is], so "forestry" is not enough for google scholar to pick up on when looking for "ecology"

Comment: Idk if that was useful at all, but hopefully understanding the reason helps with the situation at least a little bit

Answer (score 0):

I solved my first question:

problem was in ["onclick"], i used of .get() rather than [] in BeautifulSoup

```
if soup.select_one(".gsc_pgn button.gs_btnPR").get('onclick'):
                params["after_author"] = re.search(r"after_author\\x3d(.*)\\x26", str(soup.select_one(".gsc_pgn button.gs_btnPR").get('onclick'))).group(1)
                params["astart"] += 10
            else:
                break
```

Comment: random note:  you might like the [walrus operator](https://realpython.com/python-walrus-operator/) in the `if` here - like `if (onclick:=soup.select_one(".gsc_pgn button.gs_btnPR").get('onclick')):` so that you can just use `onclick` instead of having to use *`str(soup.select_one....)`* again for `params["after_author"]`. [Sorry if that's unwanted commentary - it's just that the line is *really* long and it doesn't need to be...]

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the article/SO answer you've shared.

Try using [`scrape-google-scholar-py`](https://github.com/dimitryzub/scrape-google-scholar-py#example-usage-custom-backend) (it will bypass `429` status code), it will solve your first question, unless you want to use your own proxies and CAPTCHA solver.

It uses `selenium-stealth` to bypass the IP rate limit and CAPTCHA which you got (could solve CloudFlare CAPTCHA):

```py
from google_scholar_py import CustomGoogleScholarProfiles
import json

parser = CustomGoogleScholarProfiles()
data = parser.scrape_google_scholar_profiles(
    query='blizzard',
    pagination=False,
    save_to_csv=False,
    save_to_json=False
)
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Installing package locally currently works better in comparison to running it on [replit](https://replit.com/) (I think it's because replit uses a lower Python version)

---

Regarding your second question. Do you have success returning a correct response on Google Scholar itself when searching?

As Driftr95 mentioned, it's possible that Google Scholar just doesn't have enough information to return the data you need, either because of the search query or lack of some data that the Google Scholar author left blank.

Try a different search query or find out what other search operators could use when searching Google Scholar.